# Like doesn't work properly with limit?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

hello guys I have problem with mysql like and limit command when used together they return 0 null I tried this in my php then I go to test it inside phpmyadmin I get the same result here is the code

```
//mysql

SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE name like '%php%' LIMIT 9,9;  //this return null
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE name like '%php%' LIMIT 9 OFFSET 9;  //this return null

SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE name like '%php%';//this return some results 

//this is weird please help here is the php code that I use


//php

$db = DB::getInstance();

$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE name LIKE ? LIMIT {$start},9",array("'%{$search}%'"));//the query function does the bindvalue

//$start come form $_GET['page'];
//$start equation // $start = ($_GET['page'] * $perpage) - $perpage
//the $perpage is always 9 cause I want to display 9 always or less
//and for sure I check for them if they were set , empty , and escape them etc...

$results = $results->results();

printItems($results);//a function that print items in a special way
```

Comment: "this returns some results" - how many?

Comment: Any less than 9 and you won't get any results as you've set the offset to 9.

Comment: You also need to remove the single quotes around the variable, you don't quote values when you use a prepared statement.

Comment: it return one result which is the only record that has php word in it thanks all I guess yeah the problem was cause of those quotes you are right cause when I removed them it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say how many results you get when you have no limit set, but I assume it's less than 9?

The `LIMIT 9,9` or `LIMIT 9 OFFSET 9` sets a limit of 9 results total, but starts looking **from result number 9**. If there are less than 9 results, you will get 0 results returned. I'm guessing you have misunderstood the offset-part of the limit clause (which aren't needed).

Remove the `OFFSET`-part, and you'll get a result back, even with `LIMIT` present.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have enough data that satisfy `LIMIT 9, 9`

`LIMIT 9, 9` means retrieve rows from 10 to 18

Comment: yeah I know the record that I target is at row 10 so it should pop up btw I solved the problem I don't know what it was I just solved it thanks any way

Comment: Can you please paste your solution?

Comment: $db = DB::getInstance();

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE ? LIMIT {$start}, 9";
  $results = $db->query($sql,array("%{$search}%"));
  $results = $results->results();
  printItems($results);